# How to download file in angular cli?

Tags: angular

I have a problem when downloading a file, when I get a response from the backend how do I download the file?

The error is when I want to get the file name

this my .ts :

```
async download(path: any) {
    const { status, headers, body } = await this.studentService.download(path);
     const filenames = this.Filename(headers);
    const blob = new Blob([body],{type:'application/octet-stream'});
    saveAs(blob, filenames);

  }

  Filename(headers: any) {
    let filenames = '';
    var RGX_FILENAME = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
    const contentDisposition = headers.get('Content-Disposition');
    const matches = RGX_FILENAME.exec(contentDisposition);
    if (matches && matches[1]) {
      filenames = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
    }
    return filenames;
  }
```

this my .service :

```
async download(param: any): Promise<any> {
    const query = this.paramFile(param);
    const result = await this.get(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/file/${query}`
    );
    return result;
  }

  paramFile(param: any) {
    const query = `${param}`;
    return query;
  }
```

I beg for your help, the deadline is 2 hours, so I hope someone can help me and guide me to the end

Answer (score 0):

Just call your service which should basically return the byte array and then save it to the blob in this way. You can chnage the type as required.

In your ts:

```
this.yourservice.downloadFile().subscribe((resp) => {
        const fileName = resp.headers.get('filename') ? resp.headers.get('filename') : 'file1_' + new Date();
        const data = resp.body;
        this.blob = new Blob([data], {
            type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        });
        var downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = downloadUrl;
        link.download = fileName + '.xlsx';
        link.click();
    }, error => {
       console.log("Error downloading the file!!!");

    });
```

service code:

```
 downloadFile() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Accept', 'application/xlsx; charset=utf-8');
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}dowmloadxls`;
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set("userId", userId);
    return this.http.get(url, { params, headers, observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' });
  }
```